# A function in a controller is completely ignored by a web browser. No error is shown but anything inside of function cannot be shown anyhow

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently working on a project with AngularJS and I have a controller named "categoryController" which is looking like this:

```
controller('CategoryController',
        [
            '$scope',
            'dataService',
            function ($scope, dataService){
                console.log("Here is working");
                var getCategory = function () {
                    dataService.getCategory().then(  // then() is called when the promise is resolve or rejected
                        function (response){
                            console.log("But this is not working");
                            //$scope.BooksCount  = response.rowCount + ' books';
                            $scope.category      = response.data;
                        },
                        function(err){
                            $scope.status = 'Unable to load data ' + err;
                        },
                        function(notify){
                            console.log(notify);
                        }
                    ); // end of getBooks().then
                };
            }
        ]
    );
```

So as you see, the first console.log somehow shows the message, while the second one cannot be seen in the console in the browser.
Does anyone have any idea why this function getCategory is completely ignored?

Comment: did you try putting a breakpoint ?

Comment: I put the debugger; inside of this function getCategory, but it didn't even break at that point.

Comment: @yeehui From above code, i dont see anywhere calling that function. Are yiu trying to call the function from view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have only defined the getCategory function in the controller.

You also need to invoke the function

```
controller('CategoryController',
        [
            '$scope',
            'dataService',
            function ($scope, dataService){
                console.log("Here is working");
                var getCategory = function () {
                    dataService.getCategory().then(  // then() is called when the promise is resolve or rejected
                        function (response){
                            console.log("But this is not working");
                            //$scope.BooksCount  = response.rowCount + ' books';
                            $scope.category      = response.data;
                        },
                        function(err){
                            $scope.status = 'Unable to load data ' + err;
                        },
                        function(notify){
                            console.log(notify);
                        }
                    ); // end of getBooks().then
                };
                //Invoke the function
                getCategory();
            }
        ]
    );
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! I missed that very simple thing so badly. Thank you very much for your quick reply!